# Simplifying expression and its condition

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify the expression and decide for which
'x'
it makes sense

$$\frac{1-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x-1}}}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x+1}}}$$

what is simplification and conditions of x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{1-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x-1}}}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x+1}}}
=\frac{1-\frac{1}{\frac{x-2}{x-1}}}{1+\frac{1}{\frac{x+2}{x+1}}}
=\frac{1-\frac{x-1}{x-2}}{1+\frac{x+1}{x+2}}
=\frac{\frac{-1}{x-2}}{\frac{2x+3}{x+2}}=-\frac{x+2}{(2x+3)(x-2)}$$

with $x\neq 1,-1,2,-2,-\frac32$

Answer (score 3):

We have:
$$1-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x-1}} = 1-\frac{x-1}{x-2} = \frac{x-2-x+1}{x-2}=\frac{-1}{x-2}$$

and

$$1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x+1}} = 1+\frac{x+1}{x+2} = \frac{2x+3}{x+2}$$

so

$$\frac{1-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x-1}}}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x+1}}} = \frac{\frac{-1}{x-2}}{\frac{2x+3}{x+2}} = -\frac{x+2}{(x-2)(2x+3)}$$

and it makes sense $\forall x \not= 2, -2, 1, -1$ and $\dfrac{-3}{2}$ which is where the denominator is zero.

---

$\underline{\text{Side note}}$: However, $2$ and $\dfrac{-3}{2}$ are the only real poles, while the others are removable singularities, so we can extend by continuity.

Comment: Well, $2$ and $-\frac 32$ are the only real poles, in the other values we can extend by continuity. I think it is also the purpose of the exercise to categorize the $5$ points between removable and persistent singularities.

Comment: I agree @zwim . I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: @zwim Yes of course we can remove those discontinuity but with reference to the original expression for $x=1,-1,,-2$ it is not well defined. The question is not about the continuity of the expression but about the simplification, thus I'm not sure that this was the point of the OP. For example also the expression $\frac1x$ makes sense for all $x$ if we set $1/x=1$ for $x=0$.

Comment: @F.A. with reference to the OP this extention by continuity is pretty meaningless, the OP is not about continuity but about equivalent expressions and to be equivalent we need to exclude that $x=1,-1,2,-2,-3/2$. I think you should rollback to the previous edit.

Comment: @gimusi Yes, but I still think it's important to address it, as a side note.

Comment: @F.A. Ok as a side note it can make sense but it is important to keep in mind that for the equivalence of the two expression continuity is completely useless here. Bye

Comment: @zwim Do you agree with this last interpretation? Please revise you comment, it is really misleading.

Comment: @gimusi I think you take this matter too seriously. It's fine either way, this was just a remark that some of the singularities are artificial and result only from the algebraic expression, there was no criticism in my comment.

Comment: @zwim I simply think that your remark was wrong, the OP stated "Simplify the expression and decide for which 'x' it makes sense" and for x=1,-1,2,-2,-3/2 it doesn't make sense. Continuity is not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$1+\frac{1}{x+1}=\frac{x+1+1}{x+1}=\frac{x+2}{x+1}$$
$$1+\frac{1}{\frac{x+2}{x+1}}=\frac{x+1+x+2}{x+2}=\frac{2x+3}{x+2}$$
$$1-\frac{1}{x-1}=\frac{x-2}{x-1}$$
$$1-\frac{1}{\frac{x-2}{x-1}}=-\frac{1}{x-2}$$
Can you proceed?